# sap.m.TileContainer only shows 2 tiles per page on smartphone

Tags: javascript, sapui5

In my application I use the sap.m.TileContainer with CSS-customized sap.m.StandardTile Tiles. My problem is, that the TileContainer only shows 2 tiles per page on a smartphone (in my case Apple iPhone 5s). Here is a  screenshot of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Y0f.jpg

I customized the Tiles using CSS, but I cannot influence the "Tiles-per-Page" behavior in that way. It seems like the TileContainer calculates the Sizes of its tiles dynamically and also positions the tiles absolutely based on the device, and NOT based on the actual Tile-Sizes. Even if I set our Tile-Sizes to just a few pixels, the TileContainer still shows only 2 Tiles per page.

On smartphone I need to show more than 2 tiles per page. Is there a way to achieve this? I hoped that the sap.m.TileContainer woud provide properties like "tilesPerPageS", "tilesPerPageM" and "tilesPerPageL", but the control does not offer anything like this. A similar concept is implemented e.g. in the sap.ui.layout.form.ResponsiveGridLayout and its columns (see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.form.ResponsiveGridLayout.html). There you have the properties "columnsS", "columnsM" and "columnsL" to achieve different rendering based on the screen-size.

Is there a way to get more than 2 tiles shown on a page?

Best regards and thanks in advance
Mirco

Comment: Have you tried with any css stuff to accommodate more than 2 tiles in the page? I have 4 standard tiles quite comfortably. Please update your question with some raw code to look into this issue

Comment: I just checked the examples on the sap.m explored page. Even here i only get two tiles per page with my iPhone 5s:

Comment: I just checked the examples on the sap.m Explored page. Even here I only get two tiles per page with my iPhone 5s: http://imgur.com/Nxheonu

I think the coding example on sap.m Explored is the best and cleanest coding-example to reproduce this issue: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TileContainer/preview

I tried a lot with CSS. The problem seems to be the absolute positioning done by the tileContainer. Tiles are positioned using the style-attribute webkit-transform: translate3d, see screenshot: http://imgur.com/01L2koH

Comment: And I really do NOT want to overwrite the attribute values for webkit-transform: translate3d for every device ;)

Comment: BWT: When I emulate an iPhone using Chrome it shows 4 tiles per page. Its just on the native device where it only shows 2 tiles per page...

See http://imgur.com/asqzc8I

Comment: try writing media query in your css to make the tile smaller for iOS and other phones.